# Passing variable from window to window

Tags: java, swing, constructor, javafx

I have encountered some problem when trying to passing value along window in JavaFX. Let's say from login page, user successfully logged in, the the username will be pass along from login page to main page. What am I trying to do is passing the userLogged from main page to another page. This is my code in main page:

```
public String userLogged = "Desmond";

public void goProduct(ActionEvent event){
     try {
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("Shop Management");
            Pane myPane = null;
            myPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("retrieveProduct.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(myPane);
            stage.setScene(scene);     
            RetrieveProductUI rpUI = new RetrieveProductUI(userLogged);
            stage.show();
            //hide this current window (if this is whant you want
            ((Node) (event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Then inside product page, I put a constructor to take the userLogged:

```
public String userLogged;
public RetrieveProductUI(String userLogged){
    this.userLogged = userLogged;
}
```

Then I display it using a label. I did in Java Swing way which passing a variable through constructor. However, I hit **InstantiationException** error by doing this.

Anybody know how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `public String userLogged = "Desmond";` into a `private` variable, and then create a public getter in the main window:

```
public String getUserLogged(){
 return userLogged;
}
```

Then you can call for this variable on the other "page" of the app by calling it by using the name of the main `window.getUserLogged()` like this, if you want to for eg. put the username into a label called infoLabel.

```
infoLabel.setText(nameOfMainWindow.getUserLogged());
```

Hope this helps :)